# vb.net - PrintDialog not appearing

Tags: vb.net

I'm almost done with my system. All I need to finish is the print process. Sadly, the print dialog is not appearing.

Here's the code for the printing process

```
Private Sub PrintReceipt()
    Dim printdialog As New PrintDialog
    Dim printdocument As New Printing.PrintDocument

    printdialog.Document = printdocument

    AddHandler printdocument.PrintPage, AddressOf printdocument_printPage

    Dim result As DialogResult

    If (result = DialogResult.OK) Then
        printdocument.Print()
    End If
End Sub
```

There is nothing wrong with the printdocument_printpage, which is basically just what it will be printing, yet, since printing hasn't even begun, I won't bother putting it here unless requested.

I want the said dialog to appear after the transaction has been saved. which its not doing for some reason. And here's the code for the save transaction.

```
Dim payment As New Payment
    mydbcon = New MySqlConnection
    mydbcon.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=sdudb"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

    If e.PaymentSuccess = True Then
        Try
            mydbcon.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "select * from itemstored"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, mydbcon)
            reader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read
                insertTranscation(reader.GetString("itemname"), reader.GetString("price"))
            End While
            DeleteItemStored()
            PrintReceipt()
            reader.Close()
            reader.Dispose()
            mydbcon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace)
        End Try
    End If
```

Ignore the mysql here. It's not the main problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialog will not show if you don't tell it to. You've forgotten to call `printdialog.ShowDialog()` in your code, and you also never set `result` to anything before checking it.

It's a simple fix:

```
Dim result As DialogResult = printdialog.ShowDialog()
```